# OnFocus event in Google Chrome issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onfocus

I am curious if anyone else has had issues getting the onfocus method to fire in google chrome? Right now I am trying to do something as below:

```js
function setInitialFocus() {
  var browseSelectedIdFocus = "${ApplicationData.currentSelectedIdEncoded}";
  if (browseSelectedIdFocus != '' && currentAdminFunction != 'viewEditRelatedAllowedValues' && currentAdminFunction != 'viewRelatedAllowedValues' && currentAdminFunction != 'createRelatedAllowedValues') {
    if (document.getElementById(browseSelectedIdFocus).className == 'openNode') {
      document.getElementById(browseSelectedIdFocus).className = 'selectedOpenNode';
    } else if (document.getElementById(browseSelectedIdFocus).className == 'node') {
      document.getElementById(browseSelectedIdFocus).className = 'selectedNode';
    } else if (document.getElementById(browseSelectedIdFocus).className == 'noChild') {
      document.getElementById(browseSelectedIdFocus).className = 'noChildSelected';
    }
    document.getElementById(browseSelectedIdFocus).scrollIntoView(true);
    document.all['treev'].scrollLeft = 0;

  }
}
```

```html
<body onfocus="setInitialFocus()" ondblclick="return(false)" style=" align:left; margin-left:0px;">
```

It works perfectly fine in IE 11 but in Chrome it never seems to even get to the setInitialFocus function. Is there an alternative method to use or something that needs to be added to get the focus to work. The current version of Google Chrome that I am using is Version 41.0.2272.89. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the code to fire when the page is loaded, use `onload` instead of `onfocus`.

That said, I recommend checking out a library like [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) so you're not having to use the DOM handlers which is an anti-pattern called [obtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: Yeah I have tried the onload()...the problem with it is that this is a page being displayed within another page....the onload() is called for the parent page and seems to not be called on this page. I will check into the jquery library....thanks for the help.